# Filter a 2d array to keep rows containing a specific value in a specific column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array

I am building an array containing associative rows by looping the following code.

```
$alllist = array(
    "link" => $link, 
    "title" => $title, 
    "imgurl" => $imgURL,
    "price" => $price,
    "mname" => $merchantname,
    "description" => $description,
);

$all[] = $alllist;
```

I am trying to filter the array `$all` where `mname` is a certain value, let's say 'Amazon'. How do I do that?

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
reset($all);

$all_filter = array_filter($all, function(filter) use ($all) {
    $key = key($all);
    next($all);
    return key($all) === 'Amazon';
});
```

Comment: Please update your question with more explicit examples of the input, expected output, and actual output. Also, try to explain more clearly what you mean by "did not work," as there are various ways that could happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this what you want:

```
$name = 'Amazon'; 

$all_filter = array_filter($all, function (array $item) use ($name) {
    return array_key_exists('mname', $item) && $item['mname'] === $name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$all[] = array("link"=> 1, "title"=> 2, "imgurl"=> 3, 
"price"=>4, "mname"=>'Amazon', "description"=>5);


$all[] = array("link"=> 1, "title"=> 2, "imgurl"=> 3, 
"price"=>4, "mname"=>'Facebook', "description"=>5);

$filtered = array_filter($all, function($item) {
return $item['mname'] === 'Amazon';
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: I tired this did not work as expected:                                                                                   $all_filter = array_filter($all, function($item) {
return $item['mname'] === $merchant;
});

Comment: What your code is different from mine ? Please paste it, because I'm pretty sure that would work in 100%. Check case senstivite of strings (try to . and '===' to be '==' because you checking types as well. Check ```strtolower($item['mname']) == strtolower($merchant);```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` will iterate over the `array` for you. You don't need to call `reset()` or `next()`.

You should look at the [array_filter() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for more info and examples.

```
$all_filter = array_filter($all, function($item) {
    return $item['mname'] === 'Amazon';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making it more complex than it needs to be. The callback should just return a boolean value. If you don't want to hard-code the value you want to filter by (e.g. `'Amazon'`), you can pass it into the callback with `use`.

```
$filter_value = 'Amazon';

$all_filter = array_filter($all, function($item) use($filter_value) {
    // without use($filter_value), $filter_value will be undefined in this scope
    return $item['mname'] == $filter_value;
});
```

Returning the boolean expression `$item['mname'] == $filter_value;` will determine which items have `mname` values that match the filter value, and those items will be included in the result.